# Find the solution set of $x+y+z=0, xy+yz+zx=0,x^3+y^3+z^3=-3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the solution set of the equations
$x+y+z=0$
$xy+yz+zx=0$
$x^3+y^3+z^3=-3$

---

Since $x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz=(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-zx)$
Put $x+y+z=0$ and $xy+yz+zx=0$ and $x^3+y^3+z^3=-3$,we get
$-3-3xyz=0$
$xyz=-1$
But i dont know how to proceed from here?Please help me.Thanks.

Comment: Are $x,y,z$ all real?

Comment: no not all real,x,y,z may be complex also.

Comment: $X^3-AX^2+BX-C=0$ with $A=B=0$ and $C$ you have found equal to $-1$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use Vieta theorem ,then $x,y,z$ is 
$$t^3+1=0$$three roots

Comment: I got it thanks.