# Solving System of Equations Issue

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, systems-of-equations

$$ \begin{aligned}
 x^2+4y^2+9z^2 &= 1 \\
 8yz+2ax &=0 \\
 8zx+8ay &= 0\\ 
 8xy+18az &= 0
\end{aligned}$$

How would I solve these equations? I tried making $a$ the subject of the final $3$ but struggling to solve it.

Comment: Are you solving for all 4 variables $(x,y,z,a)$?

Comment: Note that moving the $a$-terms to one side and multiplying the last 3 equations, you'd get another identity $xyz=-\frac 9{16}a^3$.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou I need to solve for $x, y$ and $z$

Comment: @DominikS How does that help me? Should I complete the square for equation $1$?

Comment: Sorry for the cryptic comment, I had something like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1590647/find-the-solution-set-of-xyz-0-xyyzzx-0-x3y3z3-3) in mind. Sometimes you can reformulate such systems to find that the equations determine the coefficients of a polynomial, and $x,y,z$ are the roots. The term $xyz$ would be the constant in that polynomial.

Comment: Use Matrix method or the determinant method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that $x\neq0$, $y\neq0$ and $z\neq0$ you can re-formulate the equations as

$$\begin{aligned}
 x^2+4y^2+9z^2 &= 1 \\
 (8)xyz+(2a)x^2 &=0 \\
 (8)xyz+(8a)y^2 &= 0\\ 
 (8)xyz+(18a)z^2 &= 0
\end{aligned}$$

by multiplying the 2nd, 3rd and 4th equations with $x$, $y$ and $z$ respectively

and again by normalizing the quadratic terms in the 2nd-4th equations

$$\begin{aligned}
 x^2+4y^2+9z^2 &= 1 \\
 \tfrac{8}{2a} xyz+x^2 &=0 \\
 \tfrac{8}{8a} xyz+y^2 &= 0\\ 
 \tfrac{8}{18a}xyz+z^2 &= 0
\end{aligned}$$

Now use the 2nd-4th equations in the 1st equation

$$ -\tfrac{4}{a} x y z - \tfrac{4}{a} x y z - \tfrac{4}{a} x y z = 1 $$

$$ - \tfrac{12}{a} x y z  = 1 $$

$$ \boxed{ x y z = -\tfrac{a}{12} } $$

Use the product $xyz$ in the equations above to get

$$\begin{aligned}
 -(8)\tfrac{a}{12}+(2a)x^2 &=0 \\
 -(8)\tfrac{a}{12}+(8a)y^2 &= 0\\ 
 -(8)\tfrac{a}{12}+(18a)z^2 &= 0
\end{aligned}$$

which is used to solve for $(x,y,z)$ as $a$ cancels out.

$$\boxed{\begin{aligned}
 x^2 &= \tfrac{1}{3} \\
 y^2 &= \tfrac{1}{12} \\
 z^2 &= \tfrac{1}{27} \\
\end{aligned}}$$

Finally, the 1st boxed equation above is used to find $a$

$$ \boxed{ a = \pm \tfrac{2 \sqrt{3}}{9} }$$

Comment: It seems a bit more straightforward to substitute $xyz=-\frac a{12}$ in the second set of equations instead of the first set.

Comment: @CarstenS - there are many ways to skin this cat.

Answer (score 2):

Let us use these three equations:
\begin{align*}
ax&=-4yz\\
ay&=-xz\\
az&=-\frac49xy
\end{align*}

From the first two equations you get:
\begin{align*}
(ax)\cdot(xz)&=(4yz)\cdot(ay)\\
azx^2&=4azy^2\\
x^2&=4y^2 \tag{1}
\end{align*}
The last step is valid under the assumption that $a\ne0$ and $z\ne0$.

Using similar arguments you can get: $x^2=9z^2$.

Once you know that
$x^2=4y^2=9z^2$, you immediately get
$$x^2=4y^2=9z^2=\frac13,$$
i.e., $x=\pm\frac1{\sqrt3}$, $y=\pm\frac1{2\sqrt3}$ and $z=\pm\frac1{3\sqrt3}$.

You should be able to use this to calculate $a$ and to check which combinations of the signs are actually possible.

---

All of the above was done under the assumption that $a\ne0$, $x\ne0$, $y\ne0$, $z\ne0$. So it still remains to check what happens if one of those variables is equal to zero. (I would hazard a guess that there are no such solution - but there's still a bit work to check this thoroughly.)

---

Another possibility to get $(1)$ is to view the system
\begin{align*}
4yz+xa&=0\\
xz+ya&=0
\end{align*}
as a system of two linear equations with the unknowns $z$ and $a$. If the determinant
$\det\begin{pmatrix}
 4y & x \\
  x & y \\
\end{pmatrix}$ is non-zero, then we get $a=z=0$ as the only solution. Using the remaining equations we find out that there is no such solution of the original system.

So the determinant must be zero and we get
$$\det\begin{pmatrix}
 4y & x \\
  x & y \\
\end{pmatrix}=4y^2-x^2=0.$$

Comment: One the first line of working, where did the minus sign infront of $4yz$ go?

Comment: Oh I get it $ay = -xz$ so the minuses canel.